# Jquery how to use $(this) to get value of clicked item?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have trouble getting value of particular item that I'd clicked

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            alert($(this).find("button").html());
        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>test 1</p>
    <p>test 2</p>
    <button>Yes</button>
    <button>No</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

- I'd tried `$(this).find("button").html()`, but it will return the value of 1st button("Yes) even if I clicked the 2nd button("No")
- Same for `$(this).find("p").html()`, will return value of 1st
- How do I use `$(this)` to get the value of item I clicked?
- Don't suggest me to insert class or id, I'm not suppose to touch the html.
- Please assist, thanks.

Comment: You are binding your event to the document, not to the button. Try `$("button").click()` instead. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/9khopv7k/

Comment: not sure why SO users have a habit of down voting people that clearly are still learning...

Comment: Hi @HanletEscaño , Thanks, Solved my issue, this is what I do now `$("button").click(function (){
            if ($(this).html() == "Yes"){})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `$(this).click` event listener is added to `document` object and not any specific html element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button,p').on('click',function(){
        alert($(this).html());
    });
});
```

plunker: https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/1743/

Comment: are u really sure its always window. i thought $(this) always represent the element that ha triggered the event or the element that invoked the current function/event.

Comment: Yes you're right, what I meant was the first $(this), he added the event listener to it, by default $(this) refers to window. You can check here https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/1741/

Comment: seems this is not a window object but a document object, edited my answer

Answer (score 3):

`this` in your click handler is always the document (which you've bound the handler to), so that doesn't help anything. Instead, use something like

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    if ($(e.target).is("button"))
        console.log($(e.target).text());
    } else {
        console.log("not clicked (directly) on a button");
    }
});
```

or rather just

```
$(document).on("click", "button", function(e){
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: This is the best answer IMHO, then you can use a conditional to check the element text for 'Yes' or 'No':
`$("button").click(function() { 
switch($(this).text().toLowerCase()) 
{ 
         case 'yes': 
          \\ do stuff 
        break; 
        case 'no': 
           \\do other stuff  } 
});`

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to get each button's html on click, use this.

```
  $('button').click(function () {
       alert($(this).html());
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the click event on both `button` and get the content of the html element with `innerHTML`.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('button').click(function(event) {
     alert(event.target.innerHTML);
   });
 });
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>test 1</p>
  <p>test 2</p>
  <button>Yes</button>
  <button>No</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to detect which $(this) is binded for ? Try something like this:

1. Setup an object

`<button class="btn red btn-xs editbtn" type="button" value="${rs.id}" value="${rs.id}">`

2. Function for this object

`$(function(){
        $('.editbtn').click(function(e){
            common.showSpinner();
            var idbbpdtd = $(this).val();
        });
    });`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(this).click(function(event) {
                    alert(event.target.innerHTML);
            });
        });
```

In jQuery `event.target` always refers to the element that triggered the event.